# Temporarily reroute a vent pipe

Tags: plumbing

I am adding an addition to my house.  The original vent pipe came out of the basement into a covered porch.  That porch has been removed, and will be rebuilt as a deck.  The problem I have is the new ledger board needs to attach where the pipe exits.  I also plan on putting a sliding glass door in this area eventually.  The addition is not yet built so I can’t just simply move the vent to a new location yet.  Options?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Cut it off and cap it.

Chances are it won't affect much. Most homes are deliberately over-vented and some other branch of the system will accommodate. If you find that it's a problem (causing gurgling, etc.), then move it to a temporary location, or install an air-admittance valve as an interim fix.

You can use a test cap or just a plastic bag and duct tape. There's very little pressure involved.

Answer (score 0):

I'd run it as close to its final position as possible, gluing the parts that won't move and leaving unglued the parts that will have to move later.

This is for air admittance only, so if you've got a bit of rain water leaking in, all it will do is drip down the properly sloped run into the rest of the drain. (You do have your vent sloped for drainage, right?) Of course, *air* leaking through an unglued joint is, well, the whole point.

Comment: The whole bathroom is going to move to the new addition, I planned on rerouting the main drain and everything into the new area to the right.  The existing bathroom is behind the pipes current location.  Eventually the whole thing will move but I’m concerned about cutting the pipe down or just venting it temporarily.